# Adding an Hyperlink to a variable obtained by json

Tags: jquery, html, json, href

A newbie question,
 I obtain a var from a json through a cicle like this

```
$.each(json.Links,function(i,link)
```

I will then append that variable to content using this

```
$('#content').append('<br>').append(link);
```

This works, but I also would wish to add to the link an href so that when a user clicks on the link he will be direct to another page but I don't know how to do this

Edit: Full html and script js

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Fake Delicious</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Inserir banner -->
        <h1>Delicious Testing Page</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
    coisa
    </div>

</body>
  </html>
```

Script

```
 var url="printTables.php?option=6";

 $.getJSON(url,function(json)
  {
  $.each(json.Links,function(i,link)
   { var test="test"+i;
     var but=$("<button>Show info</button>");
     $(link).attr("href", link);
     $('#content').append('<br>').append(link).append($('<div>').append(but));
     });
    })
```

The button at this stage isn't suposed to do anything. The link as I said it's correct since the html shows it properly I just now want to add an hyperlink to it for another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable with a string in it, representing an anchor tag, wrap it with the jQuery function, then *save* that result.  That will give you an actual tag that you can manipulate with jQuery further.

Then use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set its `href`.  These steps can be combined.

This works for me:

```
var linkFromJson = "<a>Hello</a>";
linkFromJson = $(linkFromJson).attr("href", "http://www.google.com");

$("#main").append(linkFromJson);
```

So for your example, change this:

`$(link).attr("href", link);`

to this:

`link = $(link).attr("href", link);`

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work on the html, I click on the link but nothing happens

Comment: Can you please post the code you tried to do that with, as well as the html that was produced.

Comment: @user697110 - don't bother.  I think I know your problem.  See my last edit.

Comment: I posted an edited version of what I did, there are still more functions but unrelated to this. I did what You suggested me now but now the links don't even appear on the html

Comment: @user697110 - then `link` likely doesn't contain what you think it does.  Step in with firebug or Chrome tools and take a look.  As I said, the code sample I posted works.  Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Just found the problem. I wasn't adding <a></a> to the link, I just had the direct url, once I did this  " link = "<a>"+link+"</a>"  "; it worked.Thanks for your help